# How to strip out all text to the right of '//' in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a procedure or function which will search // from source code and strip out all the text to right of the //

e.g   //This is not required

After the procedure or function is executed "this is not required" should vanish

Comment: Could there ever be more than one instance of "//" in the string?

Comment: No it cannot be more than one time in the string but it can be many times in the source code

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing this using a text editor on your source-controlled build scripts, rather than a procedure? Why would there be `//` in the PL/SQL source code anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function you needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION srting_rplc (strng VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   var   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   var := SUBSTR (strng, 1, INSTR (strng, '//') - 1);

   RETURN var;
END;
```

Execution:

```
SQL> select srting_rplc('BLA//Thi s is not required') from dual;

SRTING_RPLC('BLA//THISISNOTREQUIRED')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLA
```

Comment: Thanks.Could you please explain append the return of the function to another file

Comment: @XanderCage. Google out how to write a file using a PLSQL. You get lots of stuff. Try your hands out and post this issue which you face

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BLA//Thi s is not required', '//.*', '' ) FROM DUAL
```

This gives "BLA"

If you need keep slashes then use this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BLA//Ths s is not required', '(//).*', '\1' ) FROM DUAL
```

OR

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('BLA//Ths s is not required', '//.*', '//' ) FROM DUAL
```

This gives "BLA//"

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to keep the slashes.

Comment: @Gary_W - If so, then second version keeps slashes

Comment: @Oto Shahvadze There are multiple lines of a source code of clob data type.These source code passes through a pl/sql block after passing the lines having the word 'test' anywhere apart from beginning should be removed.So input is source code and I have to write something in the pl/sql block so that this happens.How this can be acheived

Comment: @Oto Shahvadze Can't there be solution like this -: REGEXP_REPLACE (source_code,'^test.*', '',1,0,'m'); Here it searches for test in beginning if it finds then removes that line.I want exact opposite if start + whitespace then keep otherwise remove the entire line